# How to preserve special characters like '&' in the views exposed filter form?

Tags: 7, views, uri

There is a view with exposed filters and few more filters added using `hook_views_exposed_form_alter`. Now these form elements/filter values are getting passed in the url like `http://my_site?key1=value1&key2=value2` .

Now when I add value something like `abc&xyz` i.e values having special characters "&", form element does not take & as the default value instead it displays `abc`.

I need to encode this "&" to `%26` and pass in the url without encoding other "&" that separate the key-value pair in the url.